# Как правильно разбить строку?

Tags: python, словари

У меня есть строка:

```
det = 'Тип продукта: Тихое,красное,сухое Страна: ИСПАНИЯ,Кастилия - Ла Манча,DO Производитель: Rio de la Luna Линейка: нет Крепость: 13% Сортовой состав: Темпранильо'
```

Как её разбить, чтобы в конечном итоге у меня получился словарь на подобие:

```
{'Тип продукта': ['Тихое', 'красное', 'сухое'], 'Страна': ['Испания', 'Кастилия - Ла Манча', 'DO'], 'Производитель': 'Rio de la Luna', 'Линейка': 'нет', 'Крепость': '13%', 'Сортовой состав': 'Темпранильо'}
```

Comment: ваши категории (тип продукта, страна, состав) не меняются ? т.е. они всегда одинаковые и не появиться вдруг новой категории

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я сделал конкретно под этот пример, но будет ли это работать прямо всегда - даже и не знаю. В чём суть: разбиваем текст по двоеточию и ищем слева слово, начинающееся с большой буквы (вернее, я ищу просто символ верхнего регистра, разбивать на слова мне лениво было, и так работает). Всё, что от этого слова и до двоеточия - это ключ словаря. То, что до следующего такого ключа - это значение, соответствующее предыдущему ключу. Если в значении есть запятые - разбиваем его по запятой и превращаем в список.

```py
def split_by_last_upper(text):
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if text[-i-1].isupper():
            return text[:-i-1],text[-i-1:]

def make_list_or_not(text):
    if ',' in text:
        return text.split(',')
    return text

ds = det.split(':')
key = ds[0]
d = {}
for part in ds[1:-1]:
    p1,p2 = split_by_last_upper(part)
    d[key] = make_list_or_not(p1)
    key = p2
d[key] = make_list_or_not(ds[-1])
print(d)
```

Вывод:

```
{'Тип продукта': [' Тихое', 'красное', 'сухое '], 'Страна': [' ИСПАНИЯ', 'Кастилия - Ла Манча', 'DO '], 'Производитель': ' Rio de la Luna ', 'Линейка': ' нет ', 'Крепость': ' 13% ', 'Сортовой состав': ' Темпранильо'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать так:

```
import re

lst = [x for x in re.split(r"\s*?([А-Я][^А-Я]+?):\s", det) if x]
res = {lst[x]:lst[x+1] for x in range(0,len(lst),2)}
res = {x:(res[x].split(",") if ("," in res[x]) else res[x]) for x in res.keys()}
```

res:

```
{'Тип продукта': ['Тихое', 'красное', 'сухое'], 'Страна': ['ИСПАНИЯ', 'Кастилия - Ла Манча', 'DO'], 'Производитель': 'Rio de la Luna', 'Линейка': 'нет', 'Крепость': '13%', 'Сортовой состав': 'Темпранильо'}
```

Comment: Да, так компактнее и понятнее, регэкспы тут к месту